# Tutorials for Ionic Android authenticated with Azure AD

Tags: android, authentication, ionic-framework, azure-active-directory

Hi I am trying to build an app with

- ionic5
- Angular8
- Capasitor

The webapp logs in fine. I used the example at https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js.git but I can't get the android app to authenticate with Azure AD. On click of login it opens up a browser tab with a URL but the screen is blank.I was hoping to get some code examples for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

In [Cordova, Ionic](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/271) and most of other hybrid mobile app development frameworks does not have most plugins to interact with the library needs to communicate with the native device constructs . Msal.js is designed to support [authentication flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows) only for Single Page Applications and JS in web apps.

​
For supporting ASP.NET app authentication please look at Msal .Net. you could also move to [Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/integrate-azure-ad-b2c-xamarin-forms/) if you would really want to use MSAL. You could port your HTML app from cordova, remove all cordova plugins and references, and use a [Hybrid Webview within Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview) to achieve the same result. 
​

​
​

Comment: I see, thank you. Our tech stack is Ionic and angular. We don't plan on creating native apps. Is there a different node package I can use which is based on OAuth2.0 and OpenID connect for authentication of SPA and mobile apps? Also, if I have OAuth2.0 and OpenID connect could I connect to any identity provider or is it more complicated than that? We have  a B2B product and the identity provider could be anyone.

Comment: @NishaBhat, The library MSAL.JS was designed for [implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow) which is mainly for SPA  . Yes you can use direct [OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code) instead of MSAL to connect to your AAD(your id provider tenant) if you have app registered in AAD.

Comment: thanks Hari, do you have a link to a node package I can use for this? I have tried a few but I seem to face issues with each

Comment: Hi @NishaBhat, You Don't require any node package.OAuth can be implemented directly with simple Get and Post requests. You need to select your authentication flow and implement it for example  [OAuth 2 authorization code grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)  and [implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow)

Comment: ` {
    clientId: '<clientid>',
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common',
    scopes:
      'User.ReadBasic.All Calendars.Read Calendars.ReadWrite Contacts.Read',
    validateAuthority: true,
    response_mode: 'form_post',
    redirectUri: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient',
    postLogoutRedirectUri: 'https://msft-astro-ui.azurewebsites.net/',
    navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
  } `
On android app,click of Login, I get redirected to the Microsoft login page. After I enter my username/password it redirects me to 'page not found'.

Comment: also, sometimes I just get a black browser page and this is the URL
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient#id_token=<>&state=<>&session_state=<>

Comment: We can help you any number of times but can you please ask it as a new question with information about code flow you are using and screen shots which will make users to easily understanda and also please verify the answer as it helps others like you.

Answer (score 0):

We used https://github.com/moberwasserlechner/capacitor-oauth2. It works well for OAuth2.0 and OIDC with PKCE for web and mobile. We tested it for Azure AD and Okta.

Comment: NishaBhat - can you provide a proof of concept on github or a code excerpt of you connecting to Azure AD using Ionic/capacitor?